# How can I limit the hosts to provision?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, ansible

I'm using Vagrant to create EC2 virtual machines and ansible to provision them. I'm using [this guide](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script), along with the `ec2.py` script for inventory.

I am currently provisioning one host with ansible, to which I've given a tag named `Purpose` (let's say the value is "Machine Purpose") so that I can do this in my ansible file (the `ec2.py` script provides this):

```
- hosts: tag_Purpose_Machine_Purpose
```

My problem is that if I want to add another server, and I want to provision that, I can't do that using `vagrant provision server2`, because that will run the ansible script, which will match the first host, too, and provision that one as well.

The reason I want to avoid that is that, even though the ansible instructions are mostly idempotent, not all of them are, so I will unnecessarily move some files etc. on node1, and more importantly, also restart the service already running there.

Is there a way to make ansible only provision the servers I specify on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the Ansible play with the parameter `--limit`. It's not very well documented but you can feed it group names as well as host names.

```
ansible-playbook ... --limit hostA
```

Also multiple hostnames separated by comma are possible:

```
ansible-playbook ... --limit hostA,hostB,hostC
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I could do that. Is there a way to use vagrant for this, though? It will be simpler since vagrant provides ansible with default options and a private key automatically. Plus, if I did it like this, I'd have to run vagrant with --no-provision and then provision manually.

Comment: I see, sorry, I have no experience with Vagrant together with Ansible.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I can use your suggestion as a workaround until I find a vagrant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the Vagrantfile

```
v.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.limit = 'all'  # Change this
```

And you can load it from the command line

```
v.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.limit = (ENV['ANSIBLE_LIMIT'] || 'all')
```

With

```
ANSIBLE_LIMIT='x' vagrant provision
```